# On macOS I am having an issue. Running 10.14.2 in all my non-sandboxed projects, in any NSOpenPanel, the right click commands do not work. Any Idea?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

While developing a Cocoa sandboxed application, I discovered that if I switched it to non sandboxed, in all the Open Panels of the application, the right click commands (Duplicate, move to trash etc.) do not work any more. I am certain they did work no more than two weeks ago, but I have reverted the project to old commits and the misbehaviour is still there. I tried everything, until I realised that this misbehaviour now appears in all my projects, if I switch them to non-sandboxed. This makes me think it may be some kind of bug introduced in 10.14.2 or something similar. I hope somebody else has experienced the same issue so that we can understand better what is going on. Thanks

P.S. I am using the latest Xcode 10.1 (10B61) and tried on several machines. It is the same misbehaviour.

Comment: Google found [Mac OS Mojave, Rename in Open...panel does not work](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8651644)

Answer (score 0):

The OS might be confused by having some contradicting leftover knowledge about sandboxed and non-sandboxed versions of the app with the same version / bundle ID / signature.

Some things to try:

- Test the app on a fresh user account.
- Delete the app sandbox container from your Home Folder > Library > Containers.
- Temporarily change app bundle ID to something new to see if it’s still affected.

Comment: Thanks, I think you make a very good point, but, unfortunately, none of your three proposed solutions have any effect.